# How to install the ftppwd utility on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ftp

I have Ubuntu 14.04 which needs the "ftppwd" utility installed.

I'm trying to run a Unix shell script on Ubuntu. The Unix shell script uses the `ftppwd` command.

As of now FTPPWD utility is not installed hence the command as such is not found on Ubuntu.

```
vagrant@dev-hadoop:~$ ftppwd; lsb_release -a; uname -a
ftppwd: command not found
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:   precise
Linux dev-hadoop 3.2.0-92-generic #131-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 20 16:16:02 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: There is no such package for Ubuntu, although there is a callable routine by that name in the package `ftplib-dev`. From what I read, all it does is find out the current default working directory on the FTP server. Perhaps you can determine that directory manually and hardcode it into your script?

Comment: I understand. However I would not be able to edit the script. I have the FTPLIB-DEV package installed. It does not help. 
How to make sure all the commands that work on my UNIX box work on my UBUNTU machine  as well?

Comment: Making sure that *all*  commands work may be a bit of a tall order. But I'm sure someone here can write a small C program that calls `ftppwd` and can be compiled to an executable program. (I couldn't, though.)

Comment: What does the script do? What does it use `ftppwd` for? We might be able to help if you [edit] your question and include the script, or at least, the lines of the script that run `ftppwd`.

Comment: Another idea would be to write a bash script called `ftppwd` that simply outputs the current default working directory that you have manually determined. That way, at least your script will work.

Comment: What my code is trying to do: 
String command = "ftppwd” + id + " dqpwd";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
========================
However, setting aside what my code does for a minute I am trying to understand how to install this utility.
=================
For example from my UNIX box, 
 whereis ftppwd
ftppwd: /usr/local/bin/ftppwd.bak /usr/local/bin/ftppwd /usr/local/ftppwd
================
From my UBUNTU box, whereis ftppwd does not return anything.